Jaeger doesn't receive OpenTelemetry logs from ASP.NET Core app
I'm experimenting with collecting telemetry data from ASP.NET Core Web API project using OpenTelemetry and Jaeger. As Web API project I use the standard WeatherForecast sample project.
Jaeger is running through the docker and in the UI I can see traces WebApiTest: GET WeatherForecast but there are no traces for log messages although logged messages are visible in the console output for the Web API project.
I've added the following code to the Program.cs:
    // Configure OpenTelemetry
    var resource = ResourceBuilder.CreateDefault().AddService("WebApiTest");
    builder.Services.AddOpenTelemetry()
        .WithTracing(tracerProviderBuilder =>
        {
            tracerProviderBuilder
           .SetResourceBuilder(resource)
            .AddAspNetCoreInstrumentation()
            .AddHttpClientInstrumentation()
            .AddConsoleExporter()
             .AddOtlpExporter(otlpOptions =>
             {
                 // Use IConfiguration directly for Otlp exporter endpoint option.
                 otlpOptions.Endpoint = new Uri(builder.Configuration.GetValue("Otlp:Endpoint", defaultValue: "http://localhost:4317")!);
             });
        });

    // Clear default logging providers used by WebApplication host.
    builder.Logging.ClearProviders();

    // Configure OpenTelemetry Logging.
    builder.Logging.AddOpenTelemetry(options =>
    {
        options.SetResourceBuilder(resource);
        options.IncludeFormattedMessage = true;
        options.IncludeScopes = true;
        options.ParseStateValues = true;
        options.AddOtlpExporter(otlpOptions =>
        {
            otlpOptions.Endpoint = new Uri(builder.Configuration.GetValue("Otlp:Endpoint", defaultValue: "http://localhost:4317")!);
        });
        options.AddConsoleExporter();
    });
    
    var app = builder.Build();

And in the Get() action of WeatherForecastController, a log message is created using
_logger.LogInformation("Getting weather forecast");

I'm running jaeger in the docker and in the UI I can see traces WebApiTest: GET WeatherForecast but there are no traces for log messages although log are visible in the console output for Web API project:
LogRecord.Timestamp:               2024-05-28T17:28:45.5285708Z
LogRecord.TraceId:                 3f5e1c94538e700560bf52ea54e426df
LogRecord.SpanId:                  71c194b5a7972343
LogRecord.TraceFlags:              Recorded
LogRecord.CategoryName:            WebApiTest.Controllers.WeatherForecastController
LogRecord.Severity:                Info
LogRecord.SeverityText:            Information
LogRecord.FormattedMessage:        Getting weather forecast
LogRecord.Body:                    Getting weather forecast
LogRecord.Attributes (Key:Value):
    OriginalFormat (a.k.a Body): Getting weather forecast
LogRecord.ScopeValues (Key:Value):
[Scope.0]:SpanId: 71c194b5a7972343
[Scope.0]:TraceId: 3f5e1c94538e700560bf52ea54e426df
[Scope.0]:ParentId: 0000000000000000
[Scope.1]:ConnectionId: 0HN3V7ECUMSE7
[Scope.2]:RequestId: 0HN3V7ECUMSE7:0000001D
[Scope.2]:RequestPath: /WeatherForecast
[Scope.3]:ActionId: 0e76b720-66a5-468c-9a77-8b55421de4b6
[Scope.3]:ActionName: WebApiTest.Controllers.WeatherForecastController.Get (WebApiTest)

Resource associated with LogRecord:
service.name: WebApiTest
service.instance.id: 97ca533a-f5a7-46fb-a108-eded9ad54627
telemetry.sdk.name: opentelemetry
telemetry.sdk.language: dotnet
telemetry.sdk.version: 1.8.1

What could be the reason that Jaeger doesn't collect log messages?

I guess the similar question already was answered https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78376719/add-logs-to-traces-with-ilogger-net-web-api

It's necessary to install OpenTelemetry.Extensions nuget and add AttachLogsToActivityEvent() when setting up logging options:
// Configure OpenTelemetry Logging.
builder.Logging.AddOpenTelemetry(options =>
{
  options.SetResourceBuilder(resource);
  options.IncludeFormattedMessage = true;
  options.IncludeScopes = true;
  options.ParseStateValues = true;
  options.AttachLogsToActivityEvent();
  options.AddOtlpExporter(otlpOptions =>
  {
    otlpOptions.Endpoint = new Uri(builder.Configuration.GetValue("Otlp:Endpoint", defaultValue: "http://localhost:4317")!);
  });       
  options.AddConsoleExporter();
});


Fair note: The OpenTelemetry.Extensions package is considered beta implementations.
